# what is sync (sync.RWMutex) in golang

Tags: go, synchronization, mutex

I am looking gorilla context to source code. I don't understand  what it does sync,mutex.Lock, mutex.Unlock exactly. it still is running when I removed mutex.Lock and Mutex.Unlock from source codes.

```
import (
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var (
    mutex sync.RWMutex
    data  = make(map[*http.Request]map[interface{}]interface{})
    datat = make(map[*http.Request]int64)
)

// Set stores a value for a given key in a given request.
func Set(r *http.Request, key, val interface{}) {
    mutex.Lock()
    if data[r] == nil {
        data[r] = make(map[interface{}]interface{})
        datat[r] = time.Now().Unix()
    }
    data[r][key] = val
    mutex.Unlock()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gorrila's context associates data structures with one another by means of a map, but [maps are not safe for concurrent use in go](https://golang.org/doc/faq#atomic_maps).

To allow multiple goroutines to safely access the same map, the mutex is used to ensure only one goro has write access to the map at any given time.

However, since [maps *are* safe for concurrent *reads* in go](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/HpLWnGTp-n8/hyUYmnWJqiQJ), RWMutex allows shared concurrent access for reading data off of the map by splitting up the two access roles, sothat at any point in time there are either no lockers, a single write locker, or one or more read lockers currently holding the mutex.